# Select shadow div text from page

Tags: javascript, jquery, applescript, shadow-dom

I have an AppleScript I wrote that gets some information from a webpage (that's not mine), but the page has recently updated so that a value I need is in the shadow DOM, and not the main DOM (as shown in the Safari's Web Inspector). Before, I was using this AppleScript to retrieve the value:

```applescript
set dateText to (do JavaScript "$('input#release_week').attr('value')" in doc) as string
```

With this being the operative JavaScript (using jQuery because the target page does):

```js
$('input#release_week').attr('value')
```

Since the evaluated DOM now looks like this:

```html
...
<input id="release_week" type="text" value="02/02/2022">
    <!-- Shadow Content (User Agent)
    <div contenteditable="plaintext-only">12/08/2021</div>
    -->
</input>
...
```

I'm always getting back the `02/02/2022` value, when I want the inner `12/08/2021` value instead. I've tried different variations, using the `.shadowRoot` property, and the `>>>` "shadow-piercing descending descendant combinator", neither of which worked.

What new JavaScript code can I use? The text I'm looking for is shown and selectable on the page, so I'm hopeful there has to be a way to get to it.

**Update 2/3/22**

[This is the page I'm trying to get the date from](https://leagueofcomicgeeks.com/comics/new-comics), and this is the page element I'm trying to read the text from (at the top of the page), which doesn't match the `<input>`'s value after you click one of the arrows:

[image: Date on page]

Comment: We can attach shadow DOM to only [a few elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attachShadow) and `input` element is not one of them. If tried it throws `NotSupportedError`.  Can you share reproducible code on [codesanbox](https://gerny.csb.app/shadowDom.html)?

Comment: @codesanbox I've added a URL and screenshot of the element I'm working with if you'd like to take a look. As mentioned, it's not a page I own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not related to shadow DOM. Following elements are maintaining the value:

```html
<input id="date_release_week" type="text" name="date_release_week" class="filter-options-date date-pick dp-applied hasDatepicker" maxlength="255" autocomplete="off" value="02/02/2022">
<input id="date_begin" type="hidden" name="date_begin" class="filter-options-date-begin" maxlength="255" autocomplete="off" value="02/02/2022">
<input id="date_begin" type="hidden" name="date_begin" class="filter-options-date-begin" maxlength="255" autocomplete="off" value="02/03/2022">
```

In devtool console if you run one of the following you'll get the actual selected date value:

```
date_release_week.value
date_begin[0].value
date_begin[1].value
```

Also, in Jquery, use [val()](https://api.jquery.com/val/) function to get `input` value:

```js
$('input#date_release_week').change(() => {
  console.log('attr(\'val\'): ' + $('input#date_release_week').attr('value'));
  
  console.log('val(): ' + $('input#date_release_week').val());

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Type something and press enter.
<input type="text" id="date_release_week" name="name" required minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10" value='add'>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can directly use the selector for div tag to get the data. Here is an example.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#btn').on('click', function(){
   alert($('div[contenteditable="plaintext-only"]').text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="release_week" type="text" value="02/02/2022">
    <!-- Shadow Content (User Agent) -->
    <div contenteditable="plaintext-only">12/08/2021</div>
</input>

<button id='btn'>GetData</button>
<label id='data'></label>
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood - the inner `div` is shadow content, not in the regular DOM. I've updated my code snippet so it's clearer.

Answer (score -1):

So, if you can get the value of an element in the main document, you can just use `$.attr()` to get what you want. The same can be done if you know the shadow DOM, using `$('input#release_week').closest('shadowRoot').find('div')`.

As for which new JavaScript to use, or where to look for help on how to use it, I'm not sure. I know there's a new module that's part of the Web Components polyfill called `Element.prototype.getRootNode()`, but that only works for elements in the main document -- there's no equivalent for shadow roots. So, unless something like this gets added to Web Components (I don't think it will), then you're kinda stuck with plain jQuery as far as I can tell.

My best guess would be something like this:

```
var root = someElementShadowRoot;
while (root) {
    if (root === document) { // your main document object
        return; // stop traversing and return element; it's not shadow DOM!
    } else { // this is a shadow DOM node tree, recurse deeper into its hierarchy
        root = root.getRootNode(); // returns a reference node / parent node / null (if at top of shadow DOM tree) -> recursive call! if statement will keep running until it finds the document and returns nothing
    }
}
return someElement; // you've reached the top of the shadow DOM tree; this is where you want to start. It may be possible that `someElement` is not actually a shadow root node, but it will be at this point (`someElement.getRootNode() === someElement`).
```

Comment: Hi, and thanks for trying to help me figure this out. I tried the `.closest('shadowRoot')` approach, which didn't return anything. I've added a URL and screenshot of the element I'm working with if you'd like to try things out in the debugging console.